# gRPC logging in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc

I have an ASP.NET Core application that is using gRPC to connect to some Google services. I seem to get occassional gRPC errors for some reason, without changing any code. So my preliminary question is:

Is gRPC susceptible to interference by any specific operation in ASP.NET Core?

I know that is a terribly vague question, but in all my logs, I have no indication of what is actually causing anomalies in my gRPC calls. So the real question is:

How can I implement gRPC specific logging? I get error messages fine, but it doesn't seem like I get any debug information output in my log files.

Also, how do I handle gRPC errors?

**UPDATE**

I my program class (entry point), I have added:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Path + @"\grpclog.txt");
GrpcEnvironment.SetLogger(new TextWriterLogger(tw)); 
GrpcEnvironment.Logger.Info("grpc logger test");
```

However, no logs are generated. Is this an issue with my implementation of the logger?

Comment: `Is gRPC susceptible to interference` no. gRPC is just an HTTP call with a specific payload. If your client code has issues you'll get errors. If the *server* has issues, you'll get errors. Add proper exception handling and logging to your application. Post those errors in the question itself. Post the code you use to make those HTTP calls.

Comment: In any case calling a remote service can always fail. You may be hitting a rate limit, or encounter a connectivity error, or the service (which one?) may return a specific error eg due to concurrency issues. *Your* code may be blocking, resulting in a client timeout. Or perhaps your code just ignores error results, or the logging code itself may be throwing. It's impossible to answer such a vague question

Comment: I know it’s vague and I’ve tried with basic logging. The issue I am facing is I just get an incomplete result and no information as to why. I am using Dialogflow. The thing with exception handling, is the issue I just described does not throw an exception in my code. I merely don’t get a full response. I need actual gRPC debug and info level output, not only error level output. I am just not sure how to do so.

Comment: You don't need gRPC debugging because gRPC is just a payload protocol on top of HTTP. Whether you use HttpWebRequest or HttpClient, it's still an HTTP call. You can log the request and response the same way you'd log any other HTTP call. What does your code do? Do you check the response status code? Do you use another client library perhaps that hides status codes? Or perhaps you're calling a service that returns paged results?

Comment: An HTTP call *won't* throw if an error status code is returned. If you use HttpClient, you'd have to call `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` on the response message. You don't need to do that though if you actually check the StatusCode property and handle it appropriately.

Comment: I am using a Google client library and I am not sure how it is handling the gRPC interactions. I will move this question specifically to the Github repo unless there is a way I can globally log all HTTP requests and responses.

Comment: .NET always had network-level tracing although configuration in .NET Core is a bit tricky. If you use Google's [gRPC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc/) package though you can configure logging for it with `GrpcEnvironent.SetLogger` as shown [in this NUnit test](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/Grpc.Examples.Tests/NUnitMain.cs). Have you tried this? If the answer is `yes`, then again *post the code you used* and the generated logs. Don't force people to guess what's going on bit by bit.

Comment: I have updated the question with my attempt to do so. Just to clarify, all I am after is an implementation of some sort of logging.

Comment: 1. To get extra logs about what's going on with the gRPC stack, see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md. It also gives hint how to set gRPC verbosity level (to see more than just errors).

2. In general, ASP.NET core should have no influence on the gRPC stack is completely separate so these two should work completely independently.

3. Some above comments seem to indicate that gRPC C# uses .NET HttpWebRequest or HttpClient, which is incorrect. gRPC C# implementation is based on gRPC C core library that has its own http/2 client implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity, I managed to get it working